# Was Anakin really the only human who could race pods?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-phantom-menace, anakin-skywalker

I was wondering if Anakin Skywalker really is the only human who can race pods.. I find it hard to believe considering the sheer number of populated worlds. Is there any mention of any other human, Force-Sensitive or not, who can race pods? I would be okay with a Legends answer..

Comment: In the Star Wars Knights of The Old Republic videogame there are many humans who race pods...

Comment: To add a guess. Podracing is going to take an insane reaction speed to stay alive. Many other species, likely have the advantage of heightened reflexes. Think about the reaction time of real world small insects. Anakin's got the force subtly helping him - and It's unlikely other force sensitive users would enter into pod racing (via raw probability)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to the [novelisation of Revenge of the Sith](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel)) he wasn't the only human to ever *start* a race, but he was certainly the only human to successfully complete one. Note that over two-thirds of the racers in Anakin's race crashed and several died.

> A few wings of droid fighters didn’t much scare a man who’d been a
>   Podracer since he was six, and had won the Boonta Cup at nine. **Who
>   was, in fact, the only human to ever finish a Podrace, let alone win
>   one.**

Notably, this section of the book is told from the perspective of the [omniscient narrator](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/omniscient-narrator) rather than Anakin's own limited view.

Comment: This would mean that Anakin was exaggerating then when he said in Phantom Menace that he was the only human who could podrace. He hadn't finished a race yet, so he was just one of a number of humans who could start one.

Comment: @Thunderforge - ..or you could say that he was *of the opinion* that he was the only human who could successfully do it, and then proceeded to show that assessment correct.

Comment: Or, like so many six year olds, he thought he could do anything.  Or perhaps it was some sort of force enlightenment.

Comment: He was correct in that he was the only human who could podrace, from a certain point of view...